# tail -f AND allow text input

Tags: bash, scripting, tail, tty

I want to create a script that allows some interactivity by

- tail -f logfile from myService
- allows text to be entered and sent to myService

What I could not solve yet is this two functions working parallel in one terminal. I would also like to achieve something in TTY I do not even know the word for:

```
,-------------------------.
| output here output here |
| output here output here |
|-------------------------|
( fixed input line here   )
 -------------------------
```

Is this even possible to achieve from a server-side bash script executed through ssh? How?

Comment: How does your service accept input?

Comment: It is like a console, running inside screen. I simply push text to the screen session: ``screen -S $session -p 0 -X stuff "$command$(printf \\r)"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be possible with `bash` alone, but using `dialog` with the `--tailbox` feature might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be sufficient to use `screen` or `tmux` in split mode?

command sequence for screen (default keymaps):

```
screen -
tail -f <logfile>
ctrl-a shift-s
ctrl-a <tab>
ctrl-a c
<send commands via shell>
```

command sequence for tmux (default keymaps):

```
tmux
tail -f <logfile>
ctrl-b "
<send commands via shell>
```

Comment: It would be great for myself, but this feature is created for common folk - I really do not want to expose them to all the screen possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -f` never terminates, so that won't be possible - no tool can know when to add the fixed output line.

But you can do it with straight `tail`, if you wait until the logfile is written.  I'm assuming you want to send the combination into the standard input of some other command, presumably one that integrates with your provider.

```
( tail /var/log/logfile ; echo "Fixed output line here" ) | /usr/bin/nextcommand
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a continuous stream. Pretty much like a chat. When I was young and brave, MUDs worked this way from terminal.